# Brushed DC motor with CANbus motor controller and ROS

Tags: can-bus, motordriver

I am rebuilding a mobile robot platform. I have **brushed DC motors** 12VDC, Peak Current 16.9A, No-load current of 0.33A and trying to fing a motor driver. Communication should be through **CANbus**. This is the driver that I found [LINK](https://www.maxongroup.us/maxon/view/product/control/Positionierung/546714).

## Questions are:

1. What should I be aware of when looking for a motor driver/motor controller?
2. Is the driver that I found ok for the motor?

Comment: What is "CANbus"? CAN is a physical and data link layer standard, it specifies nothing about the data sent. You can't just plug some controller PCB to a motor with "CAN" and expect everything to be plug & play. You need to know the data format and higher layer CAN protocol used.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the maximum current rating for the controller (Imax). This should always be larger than the amount of current the motor will need. Your motor peak current (I'm guessing that's the stall current) is 16A, but the controller is only rated for 4.5A. If you never stall the motor, you might be fine, but if there's no fuse to protect the controller and there's a load on your motor, you'll probably fry it. 
One thing to check is if you need rotation sensor feedback. This controller looks pretty advanced. You might be able to find something in a lower price range for your size of motor if you don't need the controller to also collect rotation sensor input.